# Array of moment objects has undefined element

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I have an array of 5 moment objects:

```
const list = [moment(a),moment(b),moment(c),moment(d),moment(e)];
```

I can log the day of the week (1-7 / Monday-Sunday):

```
const daysOfTheWeek = list.map(v => v.day());
```

and I get:

```
[ 4, 1, 3, 5, 1 ]
```

now, I do this:

```
dates.reduce((a, b) => {
        assert([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].includes(a.day()), 'day is a saturday or sunday, wrong.');
        assert(b > a, 'date is not forward in time.');
    });
```

but `a` is undefined, why would a or b be undefined in the reduce call?

There error I get:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'day' of undefined
```

What am I overlooking here?

Comment: Because you are not returning anything to the callback

Comment: You should also have a starting value (the second param) I think it starts a `null` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Ughh yeah, I forgot to return something from the reduce callback, that's why the next value is undefined.

This is better:

```
dates.reduce((a, b) => {
        assert([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].includes(a.day()), 'day is a saturday or sunday, wrong.');
        assert(b > a, 'date is not forward in time.');
        return b;  // here
    });
```